# Is it OK for an OAuth client to determine the access_token server side and then pass the token to the browser?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I can find plenty of example of single page apps (which can't manage a client secret) and plenty of examples of old-school server-side apps (which can manage a client secret) using OAuth.
But for us and, I suspect, the majority of enterprisey systems, a system is both server-based and client-based.
We can easily (and securely) identify the client server-side, and we could then make the resulting (user) access_token available browser-side.

The question is, does doing this introduce a risk?

The client-server (the server-side component of the client) cannot guarantee that the browser is running its code - but it can guarantee that all access to the resource owner's data on the client has been approved by the resource owner.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The principle itself does not introduce a risk but of course you need to take care of the method used to expose the access token to the browser. One such approach is documented here: https://hanszandbelt.wordpress.com/2017/02/24/openid-connect-for-single-page-applications/

It suggests to expose a server-side endpoint that can be called with a cookie which will then return session information that may include the access token.